# Return all for where IN (1,2,3,3,3,1) clause with duplicates in the IN condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates

I need to return all values for: select...where IN (1,2,3,3,3,1)

I have a table with unique IDs. I have the following query:

```
Select * From Table_1 Where ID IN (1,2,3,3,3,1);
```

So far I'm returning only 3 records for unique values (1,2,3)

I want to return 6 records.

I need to get result set shown on the picture.

[image]

Comment: You say you have a unique ID but your table has three records with an `ID` of 3. So it's not unique.

Comment: the query you mentioned in your question, will return all data you need. BTW, you don't need to have duplicate value inside parenthesis.

Comment: You say you have a `unique` ID, but you have multiple records with the same ID.  That, by its very definition, is **not** unique.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Please look at the updated picture.

Comment: @enigma6205: I think "Bob" should show 2 times and "John" only one time right ?

Comment: Is this all the data you have? or just a sample of your all data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do this using the `IN` condition, because `IN` treats your items as a set (i.e. ensures uniqueness).

You can produce the desired result by joining to a `UNION ALL`, like this:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM Table_1 t
JOIN ( -- This is your "IN" list
          SELECT 1 AS ID
UNION ALL SELECT 2 AS ID
UNION ALL SELECT 3 AS ID
UNION ALL SELECT 3 AS ID
UNION ALL SELECT 3 AS ID
UNION ALL SELECT 1 AS ID
) x ON x.ID = t.ID
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that with the `IN` operator.  You can create a temporary table and JOIN:

```
CREATE TABLE #TempIDs
(
ID int
)

INSERT INTO #TempIDs (1)
INSERT INTO #TempIDs (2)
INSERT INTO #TempIDs (3)
INSERT INTO #TempIDs (3)
INSERT INTO #TempIDs (3)
INSERT INTO #TempIDs (1)

Select Table_1.* From Table_1
INNER JOIN #TempIDs t n Table_1.ID = t.ID;
```

Another (maybe uglier) option is to do a `UNION`:

```
Select * From Table_1 Where ID = 1
UNION ALL
Select * From Table_1 Where ID = 2
UNION ALL
Select * From Table_1 Where ID = 3
UNION ALL
Select * From Table_1 Where ID = 3
UNION ALL
Select * From Table_1 Where ID = 3
UNION ALL
Select * From Table_1 Where ID = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it. But not with IN.

```
Select 
src.* 
From Table_1 src
inner join (
 select
ID,
myorder
from (values
 (1,0),
(2,1),
(3,2),
(3,3),
(3,4),
(1,5)
) x (ID,myorder)
) T ON
T.ID = src.ID
order by T.myorder
```

Keep in mind if you want your dataset Ordered you have to supply the order by clause.