# laravel query builder whereIn get duplicate data

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-query-builder, where-in

I am currently trying to get the candidate ids of a list of candidate names i have, for this i am currenly using the below query,

```
foreach ($candidateName as $index => $row) {
    $candidateIDS = DB::table('candidates')
                   ->select('id', 'account_name')
                   ->whereIn('account_name', $candidateName)
                   ->get();
}
```

the above query looks for the candidate names i send through the `candidateName` array and outputs the data as expected.

My question is how to get duplicate data through the query. as the `candidateName` array have duplicate name records, and i need the query output to have the duplicate candidate id and name as with the `candidateName` array.

Sample `candidateName` array

```
$candidateName = [name1,name2,name3,name3,name4,name5]
```

Expected Output

```
$candidateIDS = [{id:1,account_name:"name1"},
                 {id:2,account_name:"name2"},
                 {id:3,account_name:"name3"},
                 {id:3,account_name:"name3"},
                 {id:4,account_name:"name4"},
                 {id:5,account_name:"name5"},];
```

Comment: Put tables with sample data and expected output. This way your problem will be more understandable.

Comment: @WebArtisan i have added a sample data and expected output

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/36557067/4848587.

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir Will that method work when handling 100 or more records and do you know any laravel based method

Comment: Yes, it will work with many records. Do you mean a Laravel method to implement this approach? Or a different approach?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir yah a laravel method please, and how would you recommend i use the above method

Comment: What Laravel version are you using?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir laravel 5.6

Answer (score 0):

Laravel implementation of [Return all for where IN (1,2,3,3,3,1) clause with duplicates in the IN condition](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36557067/4848587):

```php
DB::table('candidates')
    ->select('candidates.id', 'candidates.account_name')
    ->joinSub(function($query) use($candidateNames) {
        foreach($candidateNames as $i => $candidateName) {
            if($i == 0) {
                $query->selectRaw('? as account_name', [$candidateName]);
            } else {
                $query->unionAll(DB::query()->selectRaw('? as account_name', [$candidateName]));
            }
        }
    }, 'where_in', 'where_in.account_name', 'candidates.account_name')
    ->get();
```